# Change CSS of parent element when child element is clicked using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to change the CSS of a parent image (navbar's border) when the mobile hamburger menu is clicked open, then for it to return back again when clicked again/menu closed.

I have tried to target the navbar with the border using both .parent and .find selector options, but I cannot get either to work. I think I am close, but I'm struggling to work out what's going wrong. Thank you for your help.

```js
$(".navbar-toggler").click(function(){
        $(this).find('.navbar').addClass("is-clicked");
        $(this).find('.navbar').removeClass("is-clicked");
            });
```

```css
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 98;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    color: #000000;
    height: 100px;
}

.navbar.is-clicked {
    border-bottom: red;
}

.navbar-toggler {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container-fluid nav-container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">ABC.</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item nav-item-about p-nav">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item p-nav">
            <a class="nav-contact" href="mailto:michellelclement@gmail.com?subject=Hello from your portfolio!">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because when you use `$(this).find('.navbar')`, it only searches for the element with the class navbar *inside* the element.

If you want to search outwards, then you need to use `.closest()`, which will select the closest parent element that matches the selector `.navbar`:

```
$(".navbar-toggler").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.navbar').toggleClass("is-clicked");
});
```

See a proof-of-concept example:

```js
$(".navbar-toggler").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.navbar').toggleClass("is-clicked");
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 98;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  color: #000000;
  height: 100px;
}

.navbar.is-clicked {
  border-bottom-color: red;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid nav-container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">ABC.</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item nav-item-about p-nav">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item p-nav">
          <a class="nav-contact" href="mailto:michellelclement@gmail.com?subject=Hello from your portfolio!">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it works! I was kinda close haha

Answer (score 0):

The Jquery:

```
$('.navbar-toggler').on('click', function(){
  $('.navbar').toggleClass('is-clicked');
});
```

You also need to change this in your css:

```
.navbar.is-clicked {
  border-bottom-color: red;
}
```